# QStringList and boost:any_range

Tags: c++, qt, boost

How to force `QStringList` to convert to `boost::any_range`? I came to the following code:

```
typedef boost::any_range<QString, boost::forward_traversal_tag, QString, std::ptrdiff_t> NamesRange;
void myfunc(const NamesRange& strs) { /* calling for each on strs etc. */ }; 
myfunc(QStringList() << "A" << "B" << "C");
```

But it does not compile with boost 1.58.0 and VS2010. I am somewhat sure that it worked before we upgraded to the latest version of boost. But now I cannot try the previous version.

I am not sure if I should put here the whole error message, as it is for several pages long (as template error messages can be). Well, here it is:

`c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/mutable_iterator.hpp(37): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'type'
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/mutable_iterator.hpp(43) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::range_detail::extract_iterator<C>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              C=QList<QString>::iterator
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/has_range_iterator.hpp(27) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::range_detail::range_mutable_iterator<C>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              C=QList<QString>::iterator
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp(41) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::range_detail::has_type<T,fallback_>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              T=boost::range_detail::range_mutable_iterator<QList<QString>::iterator>,
23>              fallback_=boost::mpl::bool_<false>
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/has_range_iterator.hpp(73) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::eval_if<C,F1,F2>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              C=boost::is_const<QList<QString>::iterator>,
23>              F1=boost::range_detail::has_type<boost::range_detail::range_const_iterator<QList<QString>::iterator>,boost::mpl::bool_<false>>,
23>              F2=boost::range_detail::has_type<boost::range_detail::range_mutable_iterator<QList<QString>::iterator>,boost::mpl::bool_<false>>
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/mpl/if.hpp(63) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::has_range_iterator<T>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              T=QList<QString>::iterator
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp(40) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::if_<T1,T2,T3>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              T1=boost::has_range_iterator<QList<QString>::iterator>,
23>              T2=boost::range_iterator<QList<QString>::iterator>,
23>              T3=boost::mpl::identity<void>
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp(451) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::eval_if<C,F1,F2>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              C=boost::has_range_iterator<QList<QString>::iterator>,
23>              F1=boost::range_iterator<QList<QString>::iterator>,
23>              F2=boost::mpl::identity<void>
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/plain/and.hpp(25) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::iterator_range<IteratorT>::is_compatible_range_<Source>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              IteratorT=boost::range_detail::any_iterator<QString,boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag,QString,ptrdiff_t,boost::any_iterator_buffer<0x040>>,
23>              Source=QList<QString>::iterator
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/plain/and.hpp(55) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::aux::and_impl<C_,T1,T2,T3,T4>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              C_=true,
23>              T1=boost::iterator_range<boost::range_detail::any_iterator<QString,boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag,QString,ptrdiff_t,boost::any_iterator_buffer<0x040>>>::is_compatible_range_<QList<QString>::iterator>,
23>              T2=boost::mpl::true_,
23>              T3=boost::mpl::true_,
23>              T4=boost::mpl::true_
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp(468) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::and_<T1,T2>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              T1=boost::mpl::not_<boost::is_convertible<QList<QString>::iterator,boost::range_detail::any_iterator<QString,boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag,QString,ptrdiff_t,boost::any_iterator_buffer<0x040>>>>,
23>              T2=boost::iterator_range<boost::range_detail::any_iterator<QString,boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag,QString,ptrdiff_t,boost::any_iterator_buffer<0x040>>>::is_compatible_range_<QList<QString>::iterator>
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/core/enable_if.hpp(36) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::iterator_range<IteratorT>::is_compatible_range<Source>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              IteratorT=boost::range_detail::any_iterator<QString,boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag,QString,ptrdiff_t,boost::any_iterator_buffer<0x040>>,
23>              Source=QList<QString>::iterator
23>          ]
23>          c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/any_range.hpp(124) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::enable_if<Cond,T>' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              Cond=boost::iterator_range<boost::range_detail::any_iterator<QString,boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag,QString,ptrdiff_t,boost::any_iterator_buffer<0x040>>>::is_compatible_range<QList<QString>::iterator>,
23>              T=void
23>          ]
23>          ..\..\..\..\..\mypath\myfile.cpp(118) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::range_detail::any_range<Value,Traversal,Reference,Difference>::any_range<QStringList>(WrappedRange &)' being compiled
23>          with
23>          [
23>              Value=QString,
23>              Traversal=boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag,
23>              Reference=QString,
23>              Difference=ptrdiff_t,
23>              WrappedRange=QStringList
23>          ]
23>c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/mutable_iterator.hpp(37): error C3254: 'boost::range_detail::extract_iterator<C>' : class contains explicit override '{ctor}' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration
23>          with
23>          [
23>              C=QList<QString>::iterator
23>          ]
23>c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/mutable_iterator.hpp(37): error C2838: '{ctor}' : illegal qualified name in member declaration
23>c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/mutable_iterator.hpp(37): error C2461: 'boost::range_detail::extract_iterator<C>' : constructor syntax missing formal parameters
23>          with
23>          [
23>              C=QList<QString>::iterator
23>          ]
23>c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/mutable_iterator.hpp(37): error C2208: 'boost::type' : no members defined using this type
23>c:\views\DEV2\boost\1.58.0\boost/range/mutable_iterator.hpp(37): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation`

Comment: it compiles for me (runs, even) with gcc. It could be a compiler issue (try boost 1.59) or (long shot) some manually correct file (try extracting the boost headers fresh from the archive)

Comment: Thank you for giving it is try. I am using old VS2010 so it might be some compiler issue.